# PHP: remove filename from path

Tags: php

Say I have an path: images/alphabet/abc/23345.jpg

How do I remove the file at the end from the path? So I end up with: images/aphabet/abc/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You want [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Comment: What if the path is "images/alphabet/abc/"?

Comment: @zPuls3 "Given a string containing the path of a file or directory, this function will return the parent directory's path."

Comment: I disagree from this. Remove filename from path !== parent folder name. @abney317 should be the right answer

Comment: dirname() only gives the parent folder, it will fail w/o a filename in the end of path.

Answer (score 29):

> [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) **only gives you the parent folder's name**, so `dirname()` **will fail** where `pathinfo()` **will not**.

For that, you should use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$dirname = pathinfo('images/alphabet/abc/23345.jpg', PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
```

The `PATHINFO_DIRNAME` tells `pathinfo` to directly return the `dirname`.

**See some examples:**

- For path `images/alphabet/abc/23345.jpg`, both works:

  ```
  <?php

  $dirname = dirname('images/alphabet/abc/23345.jpg'); 
  // $dirname === 'images/alphabet/abc/'

  $dirname = pathinfo('images/alphabet/abc/23345.jpg', PATHINFO_DIRNAME); 
  // $dirname === 'images/alphabet/abc/'
  ```
- For path `images/alphabet/abc/`, where `dirname` fails:

  ```
  <?php

  $dirname = dirname('images/alphabet/abc/'); 
  // $dirname === 'images/alphabet/'

  $dirname = pathinfo('images/alphabet/abc/', PATHINFO_DIRNAME); 
  // $dirname === 'images/alphabet/abc/'
  ```

Comment: Did you test your examples? `dirname()` and `pathinfo()` always return the path without ending slash. And at least in PHP 8.0 `dirname()` and `pathinfo()` gives you identical results. For `'images/alphabet/abc/'` both functions returns `"images/alphabet"`. So currently there's no difference between them.

Comment: @PaulMelekhov please see the answer date, obviously it wasn't in PHP 8.0. Now if you ask me it's probably tested in PHP 5.6 or 5.4 and those comments were written by hand, they're intended to exemplify the answer and not to be some output replica, so you can ignore the trailing slash or suggest an edit to the answer.

Answer (score 19):

```
<?php
    $path = pathinfo('images/alphabet/abc/23345.jpg');
    echo $path['dirname'];
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

Note that when a string contains only a filename without a path (e.g. `"test.txt"`), the `dirname()` and `pathinfo()` functions return a single dot (`"."`) as a directory, instead of an empty string. And if your string ends with `"/"`, i.e. when a string contains only path without filename, these functions ignore this ending slash and return you a parent directory. In some cases this may be undesirable behavior and you need to use something else. For example, if your path may contain only forward slashes `"/"`, i.e. only one variant (not both slash `"/"` and backslash `"\"`) then you can use this function:

```php
function stripFileName(string $path): string
{
    if (($pos = strrpos($path, '/')) !== false) {
        return substr($path, 0, $pos);
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Or the same thing little shorter, but less clear:

```php
function stripFileName(string $path): string
{
    return substr($path, 0, (int) strrpos($path, '/'));
}
```